# What is this equivalent to?

Tags: propositional-calculus

$(p\vee q)$ $\wedge$ $(p\wedge q)' \equiv ? $

I wanna find  what this equivalent to. So my teacher has solved this but If it's possible, wanna get a solution which i can understand easily.

My idea (I mean my teacher :P):

> $\equiv p \vee q$

Regards!

Comment: First parenthesis says at least one, and the second says not both. This is called "exclusive or": $p\veebar q$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: My idea is that it is equivalent to itself.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean

Comment: lol, my teacher found that answer so i wanna get a good solution which i can understand.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(p \lor q) \land (p \land q)'\equiv (p \lor q)\land (p' \lor q')\tag{DeMorgan's}$$

Now, distribute:

$$\begin{align}(p \lor q)\land (p' \lor q')& \equiv \Big((p \land (p'\lor q')) \lor (q \land (p'\lor q'))\Big)\\ \\
& \equiv  [\underbrace{(p \wedge p')}_{\bot = 0}\vee (p \wedge q')]\vee [(q \wedge p')\vee (\underbrace{q\wedge q')}_{\bot = 0}]\tag{Distribution again}\\ \\ 
& \equiv (p \land q') \lor (p' \land q)\end{align}$$

This is, if you're familiar with it, $p \operatorname{XOR} q$

Comment: Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Well done +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(p\vee q) \wedge (p\wedge q)' &\equiv & (p\vee q) \wedge (p'\vee q')\\
 & \equiv&  
[p \wedge (p'\vee q')]\vee [q \wedge (p'\vee q')]\\
& \equiv & [(p \wedge p')\vee (p \wedge q')]\vee [(q \wedge p')\vee (q\wedge q')] \\
& \equiv & (p \wedge q')\vee (q \wedge p')
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

Read it in English: "P or Q but not both"  ... that's the exclusive or!

Comment: Thanks sir! I'll try.